# Number Theory Contest Problem Proof Based

Tags: number-theory

A positive integer n is called exceptional, if each positive integer d ≤ √n divides n. Either determine the largest exceptional n or prove that there exist arbitrarily large exceptional integers.

I tried a case with inequalities, one where k (optimistically hoping k!=n are the only solutions...) is less than or equal to sqrt(k!) and one where it is lower(the tricky one).

Comment: Closing seems unreasonable. OP mentioned some exploration.

Answer (score 4):

Let $n$ be say $\gt 12^2$. Then by Bertrand's Postulate (a theorem since the time of Chebyshev) there is a prime $p$ between $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$, and also a prime $q$ between $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$ and $\sqrt{n}$.

By our condition, $p$ and $q$ divide  $n$, so $pq$ divides $n$. 
But $pq\gt \frac{n}{8}$. It follows that $n$ is of the form $pqk$, where $k\le 8$.

Now consider the primes $11$, $13$, and $17$. They cannot all divide $n$. If $n\ge 289$, this violates our condition.

Now it remains to examine the $n\lt 289$ to find the largest exceptional $n$. The search is quick and uninteresting.